# Как спарсить все ссылки c объявлений используя requests,python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

[image: ss]
я смог получить абсолютно все ссылки со страниц, но никак не могу понять как получить лишь ссылки на объявления
url: ebey.deБыли попытки через select_one и find_all,но так и не получилось.
**Нужно спарсить все ссылки href именно из блока с товаром (div.class=s-item_info cleafix**)

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(link['href'])# все ссылки со страницы
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for link in soup.find_all('div', class_='s-item__wrapper clearfix')
    print(link.h3.text)
    print(link.find('span', class_='s-item__price').text)
    print(link.a['href'])
```

Comment: Спасибо большое